# load data in a file into several arrays

Tags: matlab, matrix, divide

I want to plot every value in a .dat file with data as follows using Matlab:

```
100  20  30  40  70 
200  32  122  45  483

200  388  93  344  23  222 
234  23  122
123  984  344  34

213  12  43  9
23
```

For each row, data is separated by `"  "`(2 spaces) as delimiters. An empty row (should be another kind of delimiter) separates the data into different arrays.

Therefore, I want to plot the three arrays in one graph: array 1 has 2 row with "red dot" in the graph; array 2 has 3 rows with "blue dots" and array 3 has 2 rows with "green dots".

How can I program to load the file data into three arrays (or matrices), and then plot them?

EDIT:
By the way, the number of items in each row may be different. How to pad short rows with "0"s to make all the rows have same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) :

```
strsplit(str,delimiter)
```

To split the array into different variables, you can do something like this :

```
# Where OriginalInputData is a string containing the whole .dat file.
InputData = strsplit(OriginalInputData, /n/n) #Cell array of strings
PreArray1 = strsplit(InputData(1), /n)
Array1(1,:) = strsplit(PreArray1(1), "  ")
Array1(2,:) = strsplit(PreArray1(2), "  ")
#Plot Array1
```

Apply this same logic to your other arrays. It will also fill the "empty cells" with "0"s.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I ran `InputData = strsplit(text, '\n\n');` where `text` is the string containing the whole file, I got the error: "Error using strsplit (line 81) First input must be a string." What does this mean and how to avoid it?

Comment: @user3207822 This means that "text" is **not** a string. Try typing `whos` in your invite command and tell us what "text" is.

Comment: I got error: "Error using whos Argument must contain a string". Does it mean `text` is not a string? I obtained `text` by using `text = fileread(filename);` When I tried to display `text`, it looks fine. Does matlab convert the string to other format as `text` is in a format of `%d  %d  ....`

Comment: yes, the type of `text` is double after I used `class(text)` to get its type

Comment: Onto your `whos`error, did you just write `whos`? See [**this**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html). It is a double? When you display it, it displays exactly what you wrote in your question? Maybe that means that it is a cell of doubles. If it is a cell of doubles, then that mean that it already split the data. If it is one big double (with whitespaces..?), then you can do `text = num2str(text)` to convert it into a string.

Comment: I wrote `whos(text)` and then got this error. When I used `dips(text)`, it exactly displays what in the file. And I tried `str = num2str(text)`, I got a number `str = 0.0019531`. Not sure it is a number of what

Comment: Hi Sifu, I rewrote `text = fileread(filename)` and got the type of `text` be char now:-) Now it looks like it works. And I should use `sprintf('\n')` as the delimiter of a new line. Thanks